# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException on tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, ssl

I have two servlets (A and B) running in one tomcat server(v8). Both of them need talk to third party interface.

A is using a keystore.xml which contains all the credential information(using Keystore.jar) and calls the third party(A1) jar function to send request and get response..

B is using third party(B1)'s webservice and set the ssl keystore as below.
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\test.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test");

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\test.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test");
```

The issue I am having is if I run serlvet A then A will work but B will have the error "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

If I run B first then B is working fine but A will have the same error. It looks like there is a conflict?
I don't understand why it happened. It doesn't seem like missing certificates in keystore file cause each time after I restart tomcat then either A or B works fine.

Hope I descript my question clearly and thanks for all your help.

Comment: You need to use the same means to identify the truststore in both servlets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)